# Using hugging face model in Java SpringBoot- Java Deep Library

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, huggingface

I have a Java SpringBoot Maven application. I want to integrate the hugging face model (BAAI bg-reranker-large) in my Java code. However, Hugging Face do not offer support for Java. I have seen a couple of recommendation to use ONNX and Java Deep Library. I felt that ONNX was not suitable for me as it requires the use of some Python code first before using Java.

I want to use Java Deep Library but I am very confused on how it works and how to translate the model from Python to Java. Is there a way to do it and how can I achieve that? If there are other ways, please suggest!